# Error during template rendering Reverse for 'group-edit' not found. 'group-edit' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

I ve an error when loading 'group_list.html' : 
Reverse for 'group-edit' not found. 'group-edit' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

If I supress this href reference, it works but I need this to be able to edit a group instance

this is my views.py for group_edit:

```
def group_edit(request, group_id):
    group_form = GroupFormEdit(instance=Group.objects.get(id=group_id))

    if request.method == "POST":
        group_form = GroupForm(request.POST, instance=Group.objects.get(id=group_id))

        if group_form.is_valid():
            group_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Group saved')  # message for inform user of success - See messages in html file
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        group_form = GroupForm()

    return render(request, 'imports/group_edit.html', {
        "group_form": group_form,
    })
```

my group_list.html:

```
{% block page %}

            <div class="panel-body">
             <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped col-md-3">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <th>Group Name</th>
                        <th>Parent Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    {%  for group in groups %}
                        <tr>
                            <td scope="row" class="col-md-3"><a href="{% url 'group-edit' group.group_id %}">{{ group.group_name }}</a></td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">{{  group.groupParent_id }}</td>
                        </tr>

                    {%  endfor %}

                </tbody>
             </table>

            </div>

{% endblock %}
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.imports_last, name='home'),
    path('company_create/', views.company_create, name='company_creation'),
    path('group_create/', views.group_create, name='group_creation'),
    path('group_edit/', views.group_edit, name='group_edit'),
    path('group_list/', views.group_list, name='group_list'),
]
```

and models.py:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    groupParent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.group_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find my pain point;
it is in the url
I should mention that I want to add a variable :

```
path('group_edit/<int:group_id>/', views.group_edit, name='group-edit'),
```